# Proper use of 'request'

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I am trying to find the best way to state the following.

1. You may need to request this information *with* your optometrist.
2. You may need to request this information *at* your optometrist.
3. Something else entirely.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 5):

"Request with" is not used.

Usually, you would request information *from* your optometrist, especially if you will ask it of your optometrist directly.

"Request this information *at* your optometrist" may be used in the case where you would ask for at your optometrist's office, but not necessarily ask your optometrist. You may ask the receptionist for such information.

There is also the use "request *of*", which generally means you are asking someone for something more tangible than information, or asking them to do something for you.

If you take a look at the following:

[image]

You see that "request with" and "request at" have minimal uses, and if you look at some of the samples, you can see that they are not used with your intended meaning.

Comment: Thanks! My intended meaning was indeed 'at the optometrist's office'. Would it better to fully state this?

Comment: Yes, it would be better.

Comment: Ignore that. I will rephrase the rest of the text and use 'from' instead. It looks much better. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

I would say "You may need to request this information *from* your optometrist."

In general communication, both of your examples would suffice, and would usually not be mistaken to mean something else, but taken literally:

- *with* would indicate that you wanted the information and a free optometrist on the side
- *at* would indicate that you would request the information at the location of your optometrist, but not necessarily involving your optometrist.

As Jim said, *of* would indicate that you wanted the optometrist to do the information.

Comment: _From_ is the correct preposition here, for a neutral announcement. _At_ is locative and presupposes an office visit, which may be too specific. _Of_ forms a highly formal construction and is not suitable for an announcement intended to be understood by everyone.